# How to change the color legend in fine granularity using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am very new to ggplot2 and trying to create 9 geom tile plots using this melted [dataset](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7147744/cm_melted.log) and the below code

```
cm <- read.table("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7147744/cm_melted.log", header=T, sep=" ")
xlab = expression(italic(lb)~(Normalised))
ylab = expression(italic(dti)~(Normalised))

ggplot(cm, aes(x=LB, y=DTI)) +
  facet_wrap(~Method, ncol=3) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=CM), colour="white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="steelblue") +   
  theme_bw() +
  coord_equal() +
  xlab(xlab) +
  ylab(ylab) +
  ggtitle("Comparison of different methods based on composite metric")
```

[image]

I would like to change the colors of the tiles and the legend in more fine granularity. For example if the minimum value of `CM` is 0 and maximum is 1, then the legend and tiles should be made up from 11 different colors for 0.1 step size.

Another concern is how can I turn the title color for the NA values in `CM' into white so that the main focus is only with the lower triangle.

And the last thing is can I use black and white pattern fills for these plots? Or any other suitable suggestions for print quality plots in bw.

Many thanks.

**Update1:**

while using `geom_tile(aes(fill=factor(value), colour="white")) +` I can get the below plot as it is color coded based on every distinct value of `CM`

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the plot, since `melt(cm)` has only 2 columns (variable, value), while you expect it to contain LB, DTI and CM. Probably `id.vars` is not set correctly?

Comment: I have uploaded the melted dataset into https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7147744/cm_melted.log and I guess you can directly use it without melt()

Comment: Tried that as well, but it also requires `value` in `fill=value`. Please edit the question so that the data is directly compatible with the code.

Comment: sorry for all the troubles. Now it should be ok. Kindly check again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can start with. You said that the scale should be from 0 to 1, but in your example maximum is about 0.6, so I took that into consideration:

```
p <- ggplot(cm, aes(x=LB, y=DTI)) +
       facet_wrap(~Method, ncol=3) +
       geom_tile(aes(fill=CM), colour="white") +
       theme_bw() +
       coord_equal() +
       xlab(xlab) +
       ylab(ylab) +
       ggtitle("Comparison of different methods based on composite metric")

# n equally placed breaks for n colours
n_breaks <- 10
br <- c(0, max(na.omit(cm$CM)))
split_interval <- function(v, n) seq(from=v[1], to=v[2], length.out=n)
p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(n_breaks), 
                         na.value = "white", 
                         breaks = split_interval(br, n_breaks))
```

Play a bit with breaks and number of colours to get the most suitable picture. Check the available palettes, the default hue should probably be more appropriate.
[image]

Comment: Great answer !! I was also getting closer :) I am also posting my version as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to know one last thing, is it possible to use fill patterns in black and white instead of colors.

Comment: Yes, for instance `colours = c("#ffffff", "#f0f0f0", "#d9d9d9", "#bdbdbd", "#969696", "#737373", "#525252", "#252525", "#000000")`, taken from http://colorbrewer2.org/.

Comment: for a quick suggestion - how to change the default order of plotting the graphs? For example what to do if I want to plot Methods {3, 6, 9} in the first column of the plot then {1,4,7} and {2,5,8}? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @tonytonov for his great answer. I am also sharing what I was trying in the meanwhile and the output. [Note: modified the dataset `cm` to include method names instead of numbers from 1 to 9]

```
max_cm <- max(na.omit(cm$CM))
min_cm <- min(na.omit(cm$CM))

ggplot(cm, aes(x=LB, y=DTI)) +
  facet_wrap(~Method, ncol=3) +
  geom_tile(data= subset(m, !is.na(CM)), aes(fill=CM)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("darkgreen", "green", "greenyellow", "yellow", "red", "darkred"), breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.1), "CM", limit=c(min_cm, max_cm)) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_equal() +
  xlab(xlab) +
  ylab(ylab) +
  ggtitle("Comparison of different methods based on composite metric")
```

[image: Output]